# Inverse data in R

Tags: r

When I run the code, the values are not displayed like in an array, just the inverse. How to change it?

```
library(ggplot2)

DF <- data.frame(staw_łokciowy = c("zgięcie", "zgięcie", "wyprost", "wyprost"),
                 LEGENDA = c("przed", "po", "przed", "po"),
                 stopnie = c(4, 6, 8, 10))
ggplot(DF, aes(staw_łokciowy, stopnie, fill = LEGENDA)) +
  geom_col(position = 'dodge') +
  geom_errorbar(aes(ymin=stopnie-2, ymax=stopnie+2), 
                size=.5, width=.2,
                position = position_dodge(0.9))
```

Answer (score 1):

The sure-shot way is to `reorder` both the x-asis and the color variable using the y-axis variable, i.e.

```r
ggplot(DF, aes(reorder(staw_łokciowy, stopnie), stopnie, fill = reorder(LEGENDA, stopnie))) +
  geom_col(position = 'dodge') +
  geom_errorbar(aes(ymin=stopnie-2, ymax=stopnie+2), 
                size=.5, width=.2,
                position = position_dodge(0.9))
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, it looks good the way I wanted it. Is it possible to rename "reorder(...)"to something else?

Comment: Yeps: `%>% labs(x = 'staw_łokciowy', fill = 'LEGENDA')`

Comment: I tried to add this but it doesn't work. Can you show me full code?

Comment: Oh I'm sorry, should've been `+` instead of `%>%`. The full code is `ggplot(DF, aes(reorder(staw_łokciowy, stopnie), stopnie, fill = reorder(LEGENDA, stopnie))) +
  geom_col(position = 'dodge') +
  geom_errorbar(aes(ymin=stopnie-2, ymax=stopnie+2), 
                size=.5, width=.2,
                position = position_dodge(0.9)) +
    labs(x = 'staw_łokciowy', fill = 'LEGENDA')`